# Stop SwingWorker with stop button

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I know there are many questions like this on stack-overflow with accepted answer but i just learned about swingWorker 
and i know i have to use cancel(true) method somewhere in the code but cant figure out how to use that method on pressing *stop_button*

Program is perfectly running i have removed extra code which is not necessary i just need to know how to stop the worker within code written in this style.

And also i am using *SwingUtilities.invokeLater* for

```
 package webScrapingForPhoner;    

import java.awt.JobAttributes;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.print.CancelablePrintJob;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;



public class rungui extends JFrame {
JLabel label_for_input,label_for_output,label_for_console;
JTextField number_field;
JButton start_button,stop_button;
long number=0;
JTextArea resultx;
String domainFound="";
public JTextArea runner;


//arguments for scrapper
boolean test=true;
JTextArea runnerx;
String finalDomain="no valid page found";
String userAgent="";
read useragentwa;
Long start_index;
String domain=".usdirectory.com";   
String http="http://";
long check=0;


rungui() {
 super("Usdirectory valid url finder");

 setLayout(null);

 label_for_input= new JLabel("input starting number of domain");
 label_for_input.setBounds(10,0,300,25);
 add(label_for_input);

 number_field = new JTextField();
 number_field.setBounds(301,0,300,25);
 add(number_field);

 label_for_output= new JLabel("Result will be displayed here");
 label_for_output.setBounds(10,80,300,25);
 add(label_for_output);
 resultx= new JTextArea();
 resultx.setBounds(10,100,580,60);
 add(resultx);

 label_for_console= new JLabel("pages with no data");
 label_for_console.setBounds(10,175,300,25);
 add(label_for_console);

 runner= new JTextArea();
 runner.setBounds(10,200,580,60);
 add(runner);

 stop_button=new JButton("Stop");
 stop_button.setBounds(200, 40, 80, 40);
 setEnabled(false);

 stop_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

//what to do here
    }
});
 add(stop_button);
 start_button=new JButton("Start");
 start_button.setBounds(100, 40, 80, 40);
 start_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try{
    start_index=Long.parseLong(number_field.getText());
    }
    catch (Exception exception){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "please restart program and enter a valid number", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    runner.setText("Started , take a seat and relax.");

    start();


}
});
 add(start_button);


 setSize(600, 700);
 setVisible(true);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

void start(){
SwingWorker<String, Void> worker=new SwingWorker<String, Void>(){

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        useragentwa=new read();
        userAgent=useragentwa.close();
        Document page=null;

    while(test){

        finalDomain=http+""+start_index+""+domain;
        check=start_index%20;
        if(check==0){
            useragentwa=new read();
            userAgent=useragentwa.close();
            System.out.println(userAgent);
        }   
        start_index++;
        System.out.println(start_index);
        try {
            page = Jsoup.connect(finalDomain).userAgent(userAgent).timeout(10*1000).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        start_index--;
            continue;
        }


            if(page.title().contains("U.S. Directory - Online Yellow Pages")){

                // area may want to append in console text area
                continue;

            }

            else{
                System.out.println("found something : "+finalDomain);
                test=false;
                break;
            }

        }





        return finalDomain;
    }

    protected void done(){

            String hereisdomain;
            try {
                hereisdomain = get();
                resultx.setText(hereisdomain);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



    }




};
worker.execute();



}
}
```

Comment: `SwingWorker` has a [`cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#cancel-boolean-), in your `SwingWorker` you should be checking [`isCancelled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#isCancelled--). You should have a look at [Canceling Background Tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/cancel.html) - this all assumes that what ever you're doing is interruptable

Comment: @MadProgrammer sir i have read that already but cannot understand how to use it within this code :(

Comment: Without some idea of what your `doInBackground` method is doing, that's as much help as we give you

Comment: *"what to add here?"* - Call the `cancel` method on the `SwingWorker`

Comment: @MadProgrammer code updated .. i know i have to call cancel method .. but how should i invoke cancel with button and where to insert method body ?

Comment: So, you need to maintain a reference to the `SwingWorker` that you created, this should be (possibly) created as an instance field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by creating an instance field to which you can maintain a reference to the `SwingWorker`...

```
public class rungui extends JFrame {

    private SwingWorker<String, Void> worker;
    //..
```

Change your `start` method to assign an instance to it...

```
void start() {
    // Check to see if the worker is already running...
    if (worker == null || worker.isDone() || worker.isCancelled()) {
        worker = new SwingWorker<String, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //...
        }

        protected void done() {
            worker = null;
            //...
        }

    };
    //...
```

Then, you need to monitor the `isCancelled` state of the `SwingWorker`.

It's important that you check before you do any "significant" work, as some blocking functionality may not be interruptible

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
    useragentwa = new read();
    userAgent = useragentwa.close();
    Document page = null;

    boolean shouldContinue = !isCancelled() || test;
    while (shouldContinue) {

        if (isCancelled()) {
            shouldContinue = false;
            continue;
        }

        finalDomain = http + "" + start_index + "" + domain;
        check = start_index % 20;
        if (check == 0) {
            useragentwa = new read();
            userAgent = useragentwa.close();
            System.out.println(userAgent);
        }
        if (isCancelled()) {
            shouldContinue = false;
            continue;
        }
        start_index++;
        System.out.println(start_index);
        try {
            page = Jsoup.connect(finalDomain).userAgent(userAgent).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            start_index--;
            continue;
        }
        if (isCancelled()) {
            shouldContinue = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (page.title().contains("U.S. Directory - Online Yellow Pages")) {

            // area may want to append in console text area
            continue;

        } else {
            System.out.println("found something : " + finalDomain);
            test = false;
            shouldContinue = false;
            continue;
        }

    }

    return finalDomain;
}
```

And finally, you need to call `cancel` on the instance of the `SwingWorker`...

```
    stop_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(worker != null && !worker.isCancelled() && !worker.isDone()) {
                worker.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

To be honest, this is just programing 101

Comment: thank you :) 
i have declared shouldContinue a global variable and change it to false . your code helped me in understanding what i needed to do :) 

BTW what is programing 101 ?

Comment: Programming 101 is basic concepts and rules which can be applied to any language/API, these are concepts you should have learned early on. I'm referring to the need to have a reference of the object you wish to work with. Also, shouldn't change the context of shouldContinue, that's what test is meant for (I assume), but you'll have issues if you try a change it's state outside the context of SwingWorker's thread